# Create StartMenu Entry

Tags: c++, winapi, unicode, path, directory

i try to create link to file in StartMenu folder, my code:

```
bool createStartMenuEntry(string targetPath, string name){
    std::wstring stemp = s2ws(targetPath);
    LPCWSTR target = stemp.c_str();

    WCHAR startMenuPath[MAX_PATH];
    HRESULT result = SHGetFolderPathW(NULL, CSIDL_COMMON_PROGRAMS, NULL, 0, startMenuPath);

    if (SUCCEEDED(result)) {
        std::wstring linkPath = std::wstring(startMenuPath) + s2ws(name);
        LPCWSTR link = linkPath.c_str();

        //TEST MESSAGE!!!
        MessageBox(NULL, LPCSTR(target), LPCSTR(link), MB_ICONWARNING);

        CoInitialize(NULL);
        IShellLinkW* shellLink = NULL;
        result = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_ShellLink, NULL, CLSCTX_ALL, IID_IShellLinkW, (void**)&shellLink);
        if (SUCCEEDED(result)) {
            shellLink->SetPath(target);
            //shellLink->SetDescription(L"Shortcut Description");
            shellLink->SetIconLocation(target, 0);
            IPersistFile* persistFile;
            result = shellLink->QueryInterface(IID_IPersistFile, (void**)&persistFile);

            if (SUCCEEDED(result)) {
                result = persistFile->Save(link, TRUE);

                persistFile->Release();
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
            shellLink->Release();
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

String to widestring conversion:

```
std::wstring s2ws(const std::string& s)
{
    int len;
    int slength = (int)s.length() + 1;
    len = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, s.c_str(), slength, 0, 0);
    wchar_t* buf = new wchar_t[len];
    MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, s.c_str(), slength, buf, len);
    std::wstring r(buf);
    delete[] buf;
    return r;
}
```

When I call my func like `createStartMenuEntry("E:\\file.exe" , "File")`, in test message I have only first letters of path and **shortcut isn't created**, I think, problem in unicode conversion.

Comment: So debug the `s2ws` function and see what it's doing. We don't have it. We can't do it for you.

Comment: Creating something at `CSIDL_COMMON_PROGRAMS` typically requires elevated privileges. Also your code discards all the error codes without reporting them. That's no good.

Comment: s2ws: https://pastebin.com/i9gW7nDd

Comment: Why do you need `s2ws()`? Set your project to use Unicode and use `std::wstring` everywhere so you don't have to convert. Also `LPCSTR(target)` and `LPCSTR(link)` is complete nonsense as you can't just cast a Unicode string to an ANSI string and expect that you get something useful out of it. This should work instead: `MessageBoxW(NULL, target, link, MB_ICONWARNING)` ... note the **W** suffix of the function name to indicate a Unicode function.

Comment: Try to understand character sets, this question has been asked a gazillion times before. And learn to debug.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple problems here:

- `MessageBox(NULL, LPCSTR(target), LPCSTR(link), MB_ICONWARNING);` is all kinds of wrong. You should not be casting strings like this. If you are compiling without `UNICODE` defined, you must use `MessageBoxW()` to display a `LPCWSTR` string. You get a single character because `"c:\\"` as a Unicode string is `'c',0,':',0,'\\',0,0,0` in memory, and that is the same as a `"c"` string when treated as a narrow ANSI string.
- You ignore the result of `persistFile->Save()`! You also ignore the results of `SetPath()` and `SetIconLocation()`.
- A normal user cannot write to `CSIDL_COMMON_PROGRAMS`, only administrators have write access to that folder, because it is shared by all users. If you are not planning to require UAC elevation, you must write to `CSIDL_PROGRAMS` instead.
- You should not use `std::string` to store paths, only `std::wstring` and `WCHAR*`/`LP[C]WSTR`, because paths that contain certain Unicode characters cannot be represented in a narrow ANSI string.